# Freemarker XPath expression to find a node with a child id

Tags: freemarker

I'm using Freemarker XML processing to build a menu. I want to find if the current element, or any of it's children have an id matching activeNode.

But I'm having a lot of trouble working out the Freemarker syntax for the XPath. This seems to match all nodes with children links (note that `item` is a node reference to the customers node)

```
<#assign aNode="search-customers" />
<#assign xpath>link["@id=${aNode}"]</#assign>

<#if item[xpath][0]?has_content>
    <#assign cssClass> class="active"</#assign>
</#if>
```

This is the relevant section of the xml I'm trying to match. For example, the `search-customers` node, should highlight the `customers` node.

```
<menu>
    <top title="title.home" url="/admin" icon="fa fa-home" />
    <top title="title.customers" id="customers" url="javascript:;" icon="fa fa-group">
        <link title="title.search.customers" id="search-customers" url="/admin/customers"></link>
        <link title="title.register.customer" id="register-customer" url="/admin/customers/new"></link>
        <link title="title.contact.us" id="contact-us" url="/admin/contactus"></link>
        <link title="title.subscribers" id="subscribers" url="/admin/subscribers"></link>
    </top>
```

Ideally it would also match the current node id - so the css should be active if either a child node id, or the current node id matches `activeNode`.

Can anyone help with the Freemarker syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out eventually, I think it's an error in the docs that put me off using the square bracket syntax....

```
<#if strVal=aNode || item["link[@id='${aNode}']"]?has_content>
    <#assign cssClass> class="active"</#assign>
<#else>
    <#assign cssClass></#assign>
</#if>
```